# Chrome & Chromium have my <ul> ONE pixel to the left and ALL other browsers show it perfect

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

it might seem very picky but I cant seem to get my menu to align perfectly under Chrome while staying correct under all other browsers.

If you take a look at `techwalrus.com` with Chrome and put the mouse over the 'Categories' menu you will notice that the UL under it is 1 pixel to the left.

Here is a screenshot of the problem.

> https://i.stack.imgur.com/fOUp1.jpg

All the other browsers display it the correct way. What do I do?

```
.nav{
width:100%;
background-color: #0066B9;
font-family: verdana;
font-weight: bold;
padding-top: 4px;
padding-bottom: 4px;
}


.nav ul{
width:960px;
margin:0 auto;
list-style: none;
padding: 0px;
}
.nav li{
display: inline;
position: relative;
background-color: #003E64;
white-space: nowrap;
padding-top: 4px;
padding-bottom: 4px;
}
.nav ul li a{
color: white;
text-decoration: none;
padding-left: 10px;
padding-right: 10px;
padding-top: 4px;
padding-bottom: 4px;
}
.nav ul li a:hover{
background-color: green;
padding-left: 10px;
padding-right: 10px;
}
.nav ul li ul{
display: none;
position: absolute;
width: auto;
left: 0;
margin-top: 4px;
}
.nav ul li:hover ul{
display: block;
}
.nav ul li ul li{
display: block;
width: auto;
}
```

Comment: It seems to be doing it at a certain browser width/s as well. As I increase width ever so slightly it goes to normal and then I increase some more and it moves left 1 pixel. This is very strange. To note, I've tried with other browsers ie. safari, firefox, maxthon, IE, and they all display it normally despite the width.

Answer (score 0):

A quick solution which can work for you

```
@media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0)
{
.nav ul li ul { margin-left:1px; }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I tried that and it seems to affect Safari browser which I don't want. I fixed the problem by moving the dropdown further to the right and now it's aligned correctly. However, if I DO have a dropdown furthur to the left, the problem comes back. I downloaded Opera and it seems to affect that browser as well. So, Chrome AND Opera if there is a way.